# How do I get my Angular app deployed to S3 respond to routing URLs

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, angular-routing

I have Angular app that uses routing, built and deployed to an S3 bucket. It works fine if I go to the root of URL of the app. e.g. `www.my-app.com.s3.foo.bar.amazonaws.com/`

And it works fine within the app. For example if I follow a router link that points to ['/home'] it goes to `www.my-app.com.s3.foo.bar.amazonaws.com/home` and so on.

But if I go directly to, say, `www.my-app.com.s3.foo.bar.amazonaws.com/home`, I get an S3 error saying the resource does not exist. This is true - there is no file in the S3 bucket corresponding to /home.

How do I ensure that URL requests get routed through the app rather than to S3?

**Update**: It looks like CloudFront might do this. What do I configure in CloudFront?

Comment: S3 is basically too ‘dumb’ to handle this. You need an entity in front of S3 that can handle the rewrites back to /index.html for you. In the past I used a cloudflare worker to do this for me. I’m sure AWS also has a solution for this? Maybe lambdas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure CloudFront to handle what is a "not found" page from the S3 perspective, by returning the appropriate root page of your SPA.

- Create your CloudFront distribution.
- Go to the Error Pages tab in the distribution config and add a new error page.
- The error you are handling from the CloudFront perspective is a 404 not found error, so enter 404 into the HTTP Error Code field.
- Select the custom response and enter the location of the root html page for your app (in the S3 bucket) e.g. /index.html.
- From the browser's perspective this was a valid request and response, so enter 200 for the HTTP Response Code field.

Comment: This worked. I also added the same for a 403 response too